# If with multiple or statements creating endless loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a loop that goes down a column and identifies if the cell equals to one of the listed security types. If it does not, it will cut and paste the data offset 1 column to the left. Sometimes the data is offset 1-3 columns which is why i added the i = i - 1 to check the same row until it satifies the if. This code leads to 2 issues:

1.) Is there a more simple line of code for the If statement with multiple or's?

2.) This code works in sections but when it runs on the whole sheet (~29K rows) it enters into an endless loop. Any ideas why this happens?

```
LastCashrow = Sheets("Cash Data").Range("A" & Sheets("Cash Data").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 8 To LastCashrow

SecType = Left(Cells(i, 5), 2)

  If SecType = "aw" Or SecType = "ca" Or SecType = "cb" Or SecType = "cd" Or SecType = "cl" Or SecType = "cp" Or SecType = "cs" Or SecType = "cv" Or SecType = "ep" _
                Or SecType = "ex" Or SecType = "fi" Or SecType = "fm" Or SecType = "gb" Or SecType = "gm" Or SecType = "hf" Or SecType = "lp" Or SecType = "mb" _
                Or SecType = "mf" Or SecType = "oa" Or SecType = "pf" Or SecType = "pr" Or SecType = "ps" Or SecType = "pt" Or SecType = "re" Or SecType = "rl" _
                Or SecType = "tb" Or SecType = "tp" Or SecType = "ut" Or SecType = "wt" Or SecType = "zb" Or SecType = "zt" Then

  ElseIf IsEmpty(SecType) = "True" Then
        Exit For

  Else
        Set Shift = Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 17))
        Shift.Cut
        Cells(i, 4).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        i = i - 1

  End If

Next i
```

Comment: check if it equals true, then check if it has a value of anything at all, then do the final else

Comment: remove the `i = i -1` and loop from the bottom.  `For i = LastCashrow to 8 Step - 1`

Comment: @ScottCraner Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1.) Is there a more simple line of code for the If statement with multiple or's?*

Yes. I'd start by improving your code this way:

```
' Declare all of your variables explicitly
Dim LastCashRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim SecType As String
Dim cell As Range

Dim validSecTypes() As String
validSecTypes = Split("aw,ca,cb,cd", ",") ' write all of your values here...
' returns an array of strings: ["aw", "ca", "cb", "cd"]

LastCashRow = 12

For i = 8 To LastCashRow
    Set cell = Cells(i, 5)
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then Exit For ' This is really the first thing to check for.

    SecType = Left(cell.Value, 2)

    If ArrayContains(validSecTypes, SecType) Then 
        MsgBox SecType & " is IN!"
    Else
        MsgBox "This is OUT: " & SecType
        'your lines of code go here
    End If

Next i
```

This uses the helper function:

```
Function ArrayContainsValue(arr As Variant, val As Variant) As Boolean
    ArrayContainsValue = (UBound(Filter(arr, val)) > -1)
End Function
```

*2.) This code works in sections but when it runs on the whole sheet (~29K rows) it enters into an endless loop. Any ideas why this happens?*

<strike>No. We'd have to see your sheet.</strike>

But are you really sure it's endless? Because processing that many rows using your code as it currently is written can take some time.

As I had guessed, your code is just taking a long time to run.

The culprit is likely this bit of code:

```
    Shift.Cut
    Cells(i, 4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: This worked great. You were correct in that it didn't create an endless loop. I believe the multiple or statements caused the code to run slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to simplify the multiple or condition:

```
If InStr(1, "/aw/ca/cb/cd/cl/cp/cs/cv/ep/ex/fi/fm/gb/gm/hf/lp/mb/mf/oa" + _
            "/pf/pr/ps/pt/re/rl/tb/tp/ut/wt/zb/zt", SecType) > 1 Then
```

Comment: I'd +1 if it wasn't that thisr does not answer to half of the question ^^

Comment: Fails if `SecType = "/c"`.

Comment: Then you use something other "/" for the delimiter, given that none of the sec types have a "/", it looks like a non-issue to me right now.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The value in the cell could happen to be `"/c"` which isn't a valid SecType value, but this code would accept it as such. (Same reasoning applies if you choose a different delimiter.)

Comment: No, I get the point totally. Your approach is certainly more eloquent. I'd say it's up to requestor to understand his data, and then choose a method he feels most comfortable with. He wanted to simplify the if, I gave one option.